# Determine arguments accepted by an exe without having source code?

Tags: c++, arguments, reverse-engineering

I have an application with which I work daily.
The developers have provided a variety of convenience arguments which when passed to the exe perform certain tasks. While debugging an issue the tech support guy told me to run the exe with some special args which reduced a lot of manual steps of my job. However, the developers are not kind enough to share a list of all such args. So I wanted to know whether there is any way to just determine the args which an exe accepts? The application is developed in C++.

Comment: do you want to determine what type of arguments accept or how many arguments?

Comment: Without looking at the source, no. That's because it can accept any arguments, even un-specified ones. For example, say the developers wrote some code to deal with `-option1 -option2`. There's nothing stopping you from calling the exe as `program.exe -option3`.

Comment: I don't think there are any actual way to do that. Your best bet would be to try using an utility such as `strings` on linux to list all the characters strings in the executable, and see what can be an argument, but I'm not sure the time investment would be worth it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing I would do is run something like `strings` (under UNIX-like operating systems) on the executable to extract anything that looks like an option.

That won't tell you how to *use* a particular option but, if your `strings` command returns:

```
--option1
--option2
--run-faster
--use-less-cpu
--format-hard-disk
```

it's a pretty safe bet that those are valid options. Shorter options may not show up so easily since `strings` tends to be for obviously textual data.

Even if you don't have something like `strings`, there's a good chance all the options will be lumped together in the executable just because of the way many compilers and linkers work.

And, as Eugeny Loy kindly points out in a comment, the sysinternals suite from Microsoft has a [strings utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439.aspx) as well.

---

By the way, I'd give serious pause before trying to test if `--format-hard-disk` is a valid option :-)

Comment: strings for windows: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439.aspx

Comment: Good find, @leo, hope you don't mind if I incorporate that into the answer.

Comment: Thanks! will try to do some testing with my application ;)